# VBA vlookup not changing values

Tags: vba

Hello I am new to the form and am having trouble with creating a VBA that performs a vlookup on a user selected case in A2.  In the attached example the values change in some cells (D2-F2) based on the selection, but the formula results, so I can not perform a select case later on because there is no value, only a formula.  The value does appear in B2 and C2 but does not change when the user selects a different case.  Thank you.

https://app.box.com/s/qrs0r5gf0vth6wpbj1w9

```
'  Step 3 Add additional selection information
Dim LastRowNo As Long
LastRowNo = Cells(Rows.Count, "CA").End(xlUp).Row

Worksheets("annovar").Range("B2").Value = Evaluate("=VLOOKUP(A2,CA5:CB" & LastRowNo & ",2,0)")
Worksheets("annovar").Range("C2").Value = Evaluate("=VLOOKUP(A2,CA5:CC" & LastRowNo & ",3,0)")
Worksheets("annovar").Range("D2").Formula = "=IFERROR(VLookup(A2,CA5:CD" & LastRowNo & ",4,0),"""")"
Worksheets("annovar").Range("E2").Formula = "=IFERROR(VLookup(A2,CA5:CE" & LastRowNo & ",5,0),"""")"
Worksheets("annovar").Range("F2").Formula = "=IFERROR(VLookup(A2,CA5:CF" & LastRowNo & ",6,0),"""")"
```

Comment: *I can not perform a select case later on because there is no value, only a formula.*  I think you're mistaken. A cell can have a `.Formula` *and* a `.Value` and it also has a `.Text` property.

Answer (score 0):

Check the ranges that you're using in the `VLOOKUP`.  I think you may be looking in the wrong column.  There isn't anything in the `Column("CA")` so `LastRowNo = 1` and `Range("CA5:CB1")` is empty.  The information that you're looking for I think was in `Range(BP8:BQ12")` because of the way that you're inserting and deleting rows every time you run it.

Would it not be better to create a new sheet or clear a different sheet every time you run the macros?  That way the code wont be so awkward?